# Simple HTML and JS login page not working, unable to fetch email and password fields on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, authentication, bootstrap-4

```
<!doctype html>

</html>

<head>
    <title> </title>
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="sigin-style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid px-1 px-md-5 px-lg-1 px-xl-5 py-5 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card0 border-0">
            <div class="row d-flex">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card1 pb-5">
                        <div class="row"> </div>
                        <div class="row px-3 justify-content-center mt-4 mb-5 border-line"> <img
                                src="https://i.imgur.com/uNGdWHi.png" class="image"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card2 card border-0 px-4 py-5" name = "login">
                        <div class="row mb-4 px-3"> <!-- fb twitter linked login-->
                            <h6 class="mb-0 mr-4 mt-2">Sign in with</h6>
                            <div class="facebook text-center mr-3">
                                <div class="fa fa-facebook"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="twitter text-center mr-3">
                                <div class="fa fa-twitter"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="linkedin text-center mr-3">
                                <div class="fa fa-linkedin"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row px-3 mb-4"> <!-- OR login separator line-->
                            <div class="line"></div> <small class="or text-center">Or</small>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row px-3" > <!-- email address-->
                            <label class="mb-1">
                                <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">Email Address</h6>
                            </label> 
                            <input class="mb-4" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row px-3"> <label class="mb-1"> <!-- passowrd-->
                                <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">Password</h6>
                            </label> 
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="row px-3 mb-4"> <!-- remember me checkbox and forgot password link-->
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline"> <!--remember me-->
                                <input id="chk1"
                                    type="checkbox" name="chk" class="custom-control-input"> 
                                    <label for="chk1" class="custom-control-label text-sm">Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="ml-auto mb-0 text-sm">Forgot Password?</a> <!--fogot password-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-3 px-3"> <!--login button-->
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue text-center" onclick="validate()" >Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-4 px-3"><!-- register link-->
                            <small class="font-weight-bold">Don't have an account?
                                <a href="E:/WebDevStudy/html-css/bootstrap%20webpage%20example/register.html" 
                                class="text-danger "> Register
                                </a>
                            </small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-blue py-4">
                <div class="row px-3"> <small class="ml-4 ml-sm-5 mb-2">Copyright &copy; 2019. All rights
                        reserved.</small>
                    <div class="social-contact ml-4 ml-sm-auto"> <span class="fa fa-facebook mr-4 text-sm"></span> <span
                            class="fa fa-google-plus mr-4 text-sm"></span> <span
                            class="fa fa-linkedin mr-4 text-sm"></span> <span
                            class="fa fa-twitter mr-4 mr-sm-5 text-sm"></span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>

    function validate()
    {
        var em = document.login.email.value;
        var pw = document.login.password.value;
        console.log(em);
       
        var valid = false;
        var usernameArray = ["ashish", "rahul"];
        var passwordArray = ["12345", "54321"];
        for (var i = 0; i < usernameArray.length; i++)
        {

            if ((un == usernameArray[i]) && (pw == passwordArray[i]))
            {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (valid)
        {
            alert("Login was successful");
            window.location = "www.google.ie";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Incorrect password or username you are now blocked");
            return false;
        }
        
    }
</script>

</html>
```

The above code is intended to be for a simple html login page where user will enter their email and password to login by clicking login button. the script for doing so is added at the end of the document following body tag. for some reason it is unable to fetch the email and password fields' values and match it with the array i have implemented. kindly point out my fault.

Comment: your if statement has `un`. did you mean `em ` instead?

Comment: oh yes made a small mistake there but fixing that also doesnt work.

Comment: try using `if(valid == true)` as well instead of `if(valid)`

Comment: yea just did it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you work with this? I tested it and it works.

I changed your

```
var em = document.login.email.value;
var pw = document.login.password.value;
```

to

```
 var em = document.getElementById('email').value;
 var pw = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

and gave your email and password inputs an id

```js
function validate() {
  var em = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var pw = document.getElementById('password').value;
  console.log(em);

  var valid = false;
  var usernameArray = ["ashish", "rahul"];
  var passwordArray = ["12345", "54321"];
  for (var i = 0; i < usernameArray.length; i++) {

    if ((em == usernameArray[i]) && (pw == passwordArray[i])) {
      valid = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (valid) {
    alert("Login was successful");
    window.location = "www.google.ie";
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect password or username you are now blocked");
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid px-1 px-md-5 px-lg-1 px-xl-5 py-5 mx-auto">
  <div class="card card0 border-0">
    <div class="row d-flex">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card1 pb-5">
          <div class="row"> </div>
          <div class="row px-3 justify-content-center mt-4 mb-5 border-line"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/uNGdWHi.png" class="image"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card2 card border-0 px-4 py-5" name="login">
          <div class="row mb-4 px-3">
            <!-- fb twitter linked login-->
            <h6 class="mb-0 mr-4 mt-2">Sign in with</h6>
            <div class="facebook text-center mr-3">
              <div class="fa fa-facebook"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="twitter text-center mr-3">
              <div class="fa fa-twitter"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="linkedin text-center mr-3">
              <div class="fa fa-linkedin"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row px-3 mb-4">
            <!-- OR login separator line-->
            <div class="line"></div> <small class="or text-center">Or</small>
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <form>
            <div class="row px-3">
              <!-- email address-->
              <label class="mb-1">
                                <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">Email Address</h6>
                            </label>
              <input class="mb-4" id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
            </div>
            <div class="row px-3"> <label class="mb-1"> <!-- passowrd-->
                                <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">Password</h6>
                            </label>
              <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="row px-3 mb-4">
              <!-- remember me checkbox and forgot password link-->
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                <!--remember me-->
                <input id="chk1" type="checkbox" name="chk" class="custom-control-input">
                <label for="chk1" class="custom-control-label text-sm">Remember me</label>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="ml-auto mb-0 text-sm">Forgot Password?</a>
              <!--fogot password-->
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3 px-3">
              <!--login button-->
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue text-center" onclick="validate()">Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="row mb-4 px-3">
            <!-- register link-->
            <small class="font-weight-bold">Don't have an account?
                                <a href="E:/WebDevStudy/html-css/bootstrap%20webpage%20example/register.html" 
                                class="text-danger "> Register
                                </a>
                            </small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-blue py-4">
      <div class="row px-3"> <small class="ml-4 ml-sm-5 mb-2">Copyright &copy; 2019. All rights
                        reserved.</small>
        <div class="social-contact ml-4 ml-sm-auto"> <span class="fa fa-facebook mr-4 text-sm"></span> <span class="fa fa-google-plus mr-4 text-sm"></span> <span class="fa fa-linkedin mr-4 text-sm"></span> <span class="fa fa-twitter mr-4 mr-sm-5 text-sm"></span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i accidently left out your css files as well. you can add them to your code

Comment: glad i can help :) small tip though, try using variable names like `username` and `password` instead of short forms. Trust me, this'll save a lot of time when you write a large code

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your inputs within a form to get values the way you want.

Look:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <title> </title>
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="sigin-style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid px-1 px-md-5 px-lg-1 px-xl-5 py-5 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card0 border-0">
            <div class="row d-flex">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card1 pb-5">
                        <div class="row"> </div>
                        <div class="row px-3 justify-content-center mt-4 mb-5 border-line"> <img
                                src="https://i.imgur.com/uNGdWHi.png" class="image"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card2 card border-0 px-4 py-5" name = "login">
                        <div class="row mb-4 px-3"> <!-- fb twitter linked login-->
                            <h6 class="mb-0 mr-4 mt-2">Sign in with</h6>
                            <div class="facebook text-center mr-3">
                                <div class="fa fa-facebook"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="twitter text-center mr-3">
                                <div class="fa fa-twitter"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="linkedin text-center mr-3">
                                <div class="fa fa-linkedin"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row px-3 mb-4"> <!-- OR login separator line-->
                            <div class="line"></div> <small class="or text-center">Or</small>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                        </div>
                        <form name="login">
                            <div class="row px-3" > <!-- email address-->
                                <label class="mb-1">
                                    <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">Email Address</h6>
                                </label> 
                                <input class="mb-4" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row px-3"> <label class="mb-1"> <!-- passowrd-->
                                    <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">Password</h6>
                                </label> 
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="row px-3 mb-4"> <!-- remember me checkbox and forgot password link-->
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline"> <!--remember me-->
                                    <input id="chk1"
                                        type="checkbox" name="chk" class="custom-control-input"> 
                                        <label for="chk1" class="custom-control-label text-sm">Remember me</label>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#" class="ml-auto mb-0 text-sm">Forgot Password?</a> <!--fogot password-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-3 px-3"> <!--login button-->
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue text-center" onclick="validate()" >Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="row mb-4 px-3"><!-- register link-->
                            <small class="font-weight-bold">Don't have an account?
                                <a href="E:/WebDevStudy/html-css/bootstrap%20webpage%20example/register.html" 
                                class="text-danger "> Register
                                </a>
                            </small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-blue py-4">
                <div class="row px-3"> <small class="ml-4 ml-sm-5 mb-2">Copyright &copy; 2019. All rights
                        reserved.</small>
                    <div class="social-contact ml-4 ml-sm-auto"> <span class="fa fa-facebook mr-4 text-sm"></span> <span
                            class="fa fa-google-plus mr-4 text-sm"></span> <span
                            class="fa fa-linkedin mr-4 text-sm"></span> <span
                            class="fa fa-twitter mr-4 mr-sm-5 text-sm"></span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>

    function validate()
    {
        var em = document.login.email.value;
        var pw = document.login.password.value;
        console.log(em);
       
        var valid = false;
        var usernameArray = ["ashish", "rahul"];
        var passwordArray = ["12345", "54321"];
        for (var i = 0; i < usernameArray.length; i++)
        {

            if ((un == usernameArray[i]) && (pw == passwordArray[i]))
            {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (valid)
        {
            alert("Login was successful");
            window.location = "www.google.ie";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Incorrect password or username you are now blocked");
            return false;
        }
        
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks  just used this code but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

form tags are missing in your code; submit button and input fields should be within form tags